# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't9.id'

Tags: doctrine-orm, relationship, symfony6

I'm on Symfony 6 and I'm trying to get my data in DB. Here is the error message I get :
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't9.id' in 'on clause'
The error is in the mapping when Doctrine requests the 't9.id' field.
Here is the script for creating my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `question` longtext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_B6F7494EC54C8C93` (`type_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_B6F7494EC54C8C93` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `type_reponse` (`id`)

   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    CREATE TABLE `reponse` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `reponse` longtext NOT NULL,
    `reponse_ponderee` longtext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_5FB6DEC71E27F6BF` (`question_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_5FB6DEC71E27F6BF` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`)

   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
   type_reponse 

   CREATE TABLE `type_reponse` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `choix` longtext NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I just want get my data... :'(
Thx for your help ! :-D

Comment: Could you expand on where your stuck? This does not look like a doctrine problem as is, could you show us the entity/mappings to know what happens? Where does this script comes from?